# Rewrite rule for language fragments in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I want to rewrite some url's in nginx and I have an wordpress site with URLs like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/en/my-content
```

How can is remove the `en/` with nginx?

Thanks a lot.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `/en` part with the following rewrite.

`rewrite ^/en(.*)$ $1;`

Comment: This might be the opposite of what the OP actually wants. I think they want requests to `/my-content` to actually go to the site at `/en/my-content` i.e. so the `en` no longer appears in the URL

Comment: This snippet doesn`t work on my site. i dont know why.
Are there any problems with varnish before the site?